# KeystoneJS show error for unqiue index failure

Tags: keystonejs

I have a model for tracking redirects like so:

```
var Redirect = new keystone.List('Redirect', {
});

Redirect.add({
    from: { type: String, required: true, initial: true, unique: true },
    to: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    status: { type: Types.Select, options: [{value: 302, label: 'Temporary'},{value: 301, label: 'Permanent'}], default: 302, numeric: true, initial: true }
});
```

The unique constraint works, I can create new models as long as it doesn't fail to have a unique 'from', but when I do create one with a non-unique 'from' I get an error in the server console but the frontend does nothing.

> Error saving changes to Redirect 5664d5860d7c730f09880de1: {
>   [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key
>   error index: keystone.redirects.$from_1  dup key: { : "/herp" }]
>   name: 'MongoError',   code: 11000,   err: 'insertDocument :: caused by
>   :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: keystone.redirects.$from_1 
>   dup key: { : "/herp" }' }

Is there another setting I need to do to get the error to show on the frontend so the user knows what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to catch that error in your server logic and present a friendlier flash message to your visitors. At least the database error message is descriptive of the problem `duplicate key error ...`

```
exports.flashMessages = function(req, res, next) {
  var flashMessages = {
    error: req.flash('error')
  };
  res.locals.messages = _.any(flashMessages,
                              function(msgs) { return msgs.length }) ? flashMessages
                                                                     : false;
  next();  
};
```

See [Common Route Middleware](http://keystonejs.com/docs/getting-started/#routesviews-middleware)

and to customize the message ensure the passed object contains the appropriate fields for the template

you can provide flash messages in your server logic by adding `req.flash`

```
req.flash(
  'success',
  'Your job has been submitted. Allow 30 days for approval.'
);
```

See https://github.com/r3dm/shpesfba.org/blob/b83d9e6a3859a83f4b4738e7a13ead08ce611bd3/routes/views/jobForm.js#L44

To display a flash error in the adminUI create an error object and pass that back into the `next` callback like so

```
Redirect.schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (saveFailure) {
    var err = new Error('MongoDB is barfing on this');
    next(err);
  }
}
```

The difficult part will be to craft your logic with mongoose [pre](http://devdocs.io/mongoose/api#schema_Schema-pre) and [post](http://devdocs.io/mongoose/api#schema_Schema-post) lifecycle hooks to catch the mongodb error. Please do some experimenting.

See https://github.com/r3dm/shpesfba.org/blob/b83d9e6a3859a83f4b4738e7a13ead08ce611bd3/models/Event.js#L76

Comment: Do you have some sample code? atm all server-side API is handled by Keystone itself so I asusme I have to override something somewhere?

Comment: This is a standard flash message code, isn't it? Keystone does have this, it is just that the error isn't getting passed to the frontend.

Comment: pretty much. Are you unable to intercept the database error in your api endpoint handler?

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify. I'll update you once I've had a chance to try it out.

Comment: That example is on the frontend, this model is purely in the admin, i.e. localhost.com/keystone/redirects. Can you manage those views the same way?

Comment: added some adminUI flash example

Comment: Same situation. If I error out in a pre save function it gets output to server log but not into a flash message. How do you get Keystone to do it? I do not have access to req inside a schema function. Thanks again for the effort you're going to.

Comment: did you generate an error object and pass it into next() ?

Comment: Yes, essentially the same code in your example without an if statement so it always fails.

Comment: are you creating new models by doing `Redirect.model.save()`? please share how you are saving new Redirects. Here is some example usage https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/cc4385037151f6c1e3af5dee342672fb6b8e6954/fields/types/relationship/test/server.js#L15

Comment: I have no code to CRUD Redirects. Keystone takes care of it all. No views have been made, just the model.

Comment: ah I see you're logged message is produced by this line https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/d85bd9109c5e30356a85739556db7d48d9f5ff1b/lib/updateHandler.js#L190 you may need to enable the option `flashErrors` to enter the branch on line 193. Try adding `keystone.set('flashErrors', true)` to your code before `keystone.start()`

Comment: That didn't work, but that piece of code will give me something to go on. We are modifying the base keystone code so I will look at why `options` doesn't get that value at some point. Thank you.

Comment: be sure to submit a PR to fix whatever the problem is. It may just be we haven't documented that option.